# How To send a GenericList Items To Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I Have a Modle like:

```
public class Invoice
{
int Code{get;set;}
List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems{get;set;}
}
```

I fill InvoiceItems in a Table and  I want Get Table Item as InvoiceItems in Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Create(Invoice model)
        {
           //Save Invoice
            return View();
        }
```

How Can I fill InvoiceItems and send it to controller?

[image]

Comment: Great MS paint abilities. Creating such table that adds items without post backs must involve AJAX. Consider making InvoiceItem a Model, first

Comment: @New Pin. post back is a term from nasty old web forms. also it can be done without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome of your html should look something like this

```
    <input type="text" name="Code" value=""/>
    ...
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="InvoiceItems[0].Name" value="InvoiceItem1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="InvoiceItems[1].Name" value="InvoiceItem2"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="InvoiceItems[2].Name" value="InvoiceItem3"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This way you can use plain form submission or ajax

```
// assuming you have only one form. otherwise use more specific selector
var $form = $("form");
var data = $form.serializeArray();
var url = $form.attr("href") || document.URL;
$.post(url, data, yourCallbackFunction);
```

The rest is done by ModelBinder. The key part is to maintain `InvoiceItems` indexes. They must start from 0 and be sequential. i.e. 0,1,2,3 etc.. If you skip some index, modelbinder will end binding your list where indexes are broken.

Answer (score 0):

lists can be represented by quasi-2-dimensional-arrays:

```
$arr = 
    array(
        array(
            {
                "key":"value",
                "key2":"value2"
            },
            {
                "key":"value",
                "key2":"value2"
            }
        ),
        array(
            {
                "key":"value",
                "key2":"value2"
            },
            {
                "key":"value",
                "key2":"value2"
            }
        )
    );
```

(json_encode)

can be read e.g. with $val = $arr["0"]["0"]["key2"];

this is just an example > use and combine Array-, Object- and Json-Syntax to get your list match your needs. working with json is very handy and features very "sourced" and object-oriented coding and easy data handling.

ps: to me your question seems rather unclear, dont know what you are exactly aiming at...